Why does this closed form appear in this random walk problem?
Two years ago with some friends, we stumbled upon the interesting result:
The expected number of picks $n$ of a number $x_k$ from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ so that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$ exceeds $1$ is $e$. (see Uniform Sum Distribution on MathWorld)
We started exploring adjacent problems, and ended up wondering what would happen if $x_k$ was in $[-1,1]$ instead, counting the number of picks before their sum leaves $[-1,1]$ for the first time. We found a completely unexpected closed form for this number, but were unable to formally prove it:

Problem: A frog lives on the real line, starting at $0$. At each step, it jumps by some amount uniformly chosen in $[-1,1]$. What's the expected number of steps before the frog leaves $[-1,1]$ for the first time?
Calling this number $E_1$, and $P_n$ the probability that our frog stays in $[-1,1]$ for the first $n$ jumps, we have $$E_1 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P_k$$
In order to compute the $P_k$, we introduce a sequence of functions $f_n$, representing the distribution of frogs after $n$ jumps. Define
$$f_0(x) =
\begin{cases}
    1& \text{if } x \in [-1,1]\\
    0& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$f_{n+1}(x) =
\begin{cases} \displaystyle
    \frac{1}{2} \int_{x-1}^{x+1} f_n(t) dt & \text{if } x \in [-1,1]\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
It follows that $f_n$ is an even function that is polynomial of degree $n$ on $[0,1]$, and $0$ outside of $[-1,1]$.
The key property is that $$f_n(0) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} f_{n-1}(t) = P_n$$
The first few functions $f_n$ are (restricted to $[0,1]$):

$f_0(x) = 1$
$f_1(x) = 1-\frac{1}{2}x$
$f_2(x) = \frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2$
$f_3(x) = \frac{7}{12}-\frac{3}{16}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2+\frac{1}{48}x^3$
$f_4(x) = \frac{29}{64}-\frac{7}{48}x-\frac{3}{32}x^2+\frac{1}{96}x^3+\frac{1}{384}x^4$
$f_5(x) = \frac{169}{480}-\frac{29}{256}x-\frac{7}{96}x^2+\frac{3}{384}x^3+\frac{1}{384}x^4-\frac{1}{3840}x^5$

A mysterious sequence $1,1,3,7,29,169,2101,17141,\dotsc$ seems to appear in the numerators of the coefficients. In particular it looks like we can multiply $P_n$ by $\frac{(2n)!!}{2} = 2^{n-1} n!$ to obtain integers:



$n$
$P_n$
$Q_n = 2^{n-1} n! P_n$




$0$
$1$
$1/2$


$1$
$1$
$1$


$2$
$\frac{3}{4}$
$3$


$3$
$\frac{7}{12}$
$14$


$4$
$\frac{29}{64}$
$87$


$5$
$\frac{169}{480}$
$676$


$6$
$\frac{2101}{7680}$
$6303$



Lucky! $Q_n$ matches A185323 (I tested it to thousands of terms), the e.g.f of $f(x) = \frac{1}{2-\tan(x)-\sec(x)} - \frac{1}{2}$. Thus $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty Q_n \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n \frac{(2x)^n}{2}$$ Which gives
$$E_1 = 2f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{2}{2-\tan (1/2) - \sec (1/2)}-1 = \left( \frac{4}{1 + \tan(1/4)} - 3 \right)^{-1}$$
Wow!

Question:

How do I prove this? As expected with such a closed form I see no way to approach it, other than pure combinatorics which makes things way too messy.
Why does this closed form exist? $\tan(1/4)$ looks like such a property-less number, and I've never seen anything like this in probability or random walks.

With the lack of a better explanation, I've been thinking of this as a "combinatorial coincidence", where both sequences just happen to be the same by chance, but maybe that's not all there is to it.

In case anyone's curious, simulation supports the empirical result with $E_1 \approx 5.3653$.

I cannot provide a full solution but perhaps one small step towards it.
Under the conditions described, denote as ${\bf T}_x$ the expected
escape time, that is, the number of steps required to leave the
closed interval $[-1,1]$ when the start is at $-1 \leq x \leq 1$,
and let $f(x)=E[{\bf T}_x]$. Clearly, $f$ is mirror-symmetric
w.r.t. $x=0$, and the problem asks for an account of $f(0)$.
The graph below shows the form of $f$ in $[-1,1]$. Note that
$f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Starting at $x$, and conditioning on the size ${\bf U}=u$ of the first step,
we get
\begin{eqnarray*} 
f(x) \; = \; E[{\bf T}_x]  & = & \frac{1}{2} \, \int_{-1}^{1} \, E[{\bf T}_x|{\bf U} = u] \, du 
\end{eqnarray*}
The new position after one step is $x+{\bf U}$.
Now, if $|x+{\bf U}|>1$ then ${\bf T}_x=1$.
Otherwise one step is consumed, the process continues from $x+{\bf U}$, and given ${\bf U} = u$, the conditional expected escape time
is $1+{\bf T}_{x+u}$. Inserting and elementary simplifications then
give
\begin{eqnarray*} 
f(x)  & = & 1 \, + \, \frac{1}{2} \, \int_{-1+|x|}^{1} \, f(v) \, dv  
\end{eqnarray*}
As $f$ is mirror-symmetric, it is sufficient to consider $x \geq 0$.
For example, the probabilistic meaning for a start at $x=1$ is that
with probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ the step will be positive and then
${\bf T}_1=1$. Else, the first step will be an amount to the left
which has a unit uniform density, and so on average the additional
number of steps required to escape must be the average across
$f$ on $[0,1]$, that is, $\int_0^1 f(v) dv$.
Differentiating the last eq. for $x \geq 0$ we get, using $f(x)=f(-x)$
\begin{eqnarray*} 
2 f'(x)  & = & -f(1-x) 
\end{eqnarray*}
a first-order delayed differential equation.
For example, we have $f(0)=-2f'(1)$.
I am not sufficiently familiar with delayed diff. eq.s to be able to provide
a closed-form analytical solution.

The delayed differential equation is
$$
f'(x)=-\frac12 f(1-x)=-\frac12 f(x-1)
$$
The usual ansatz is
$$
f(x) = c e^{\sigma x}
$$
such that
$$
\sigma-a e^{-\sigma}=0,\quad a=-1/2
$$
The solution is known as the Lambert function $W(a)$, here $W(-1/2)=-0.794023\ldots +0.77011i$.
The fact that the real part of $W(-1/2)$ is negative means that the solution is "stable."

To finish the argument started by lupus, differentiate again to get $4f''(x) = 2f'(1-x) = -f(x)$ for $0 \le x \le 1$, and solve this differential equation with the boundary condition $f(0) = -2f'(1)$ and one more condition, say $f(1) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f(v)\,dv$.  The general solution of the second-order differential equation is $A \cos \frac{x}{2} + B\sin\frac{x}{2}$. The solution to the original problem is $f(0) = A$. To find the coefficients $A$ and $B$ it is helpful to use the formulae $\cos \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, where $t = \tan \frac{1}{4}$.  We end up with $A = \frac{1+t}{1-3t}$ and $B = \frac{t-1}{1-3t}$.
